# Why do we specify a delegate along with an event, why not just use an event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, syntax, delegates, observer-pattern

Why do we specify a delegate along with the event, why not just use event in C#?

For instance, I have the following code:

```
class Shop
{
    internal delegate void _EventHandler(object sender, GoodsInfoEventArgs e);
    internal event _EventHandler GoodsArrived;

    public void BringGoods(string goods)
    {
        if (GoodsArrived != null)
        {
            GoodsArrived(this, new GoodsInfoEventArgs(goods));
        }
    }
}
```

Why would not those who have developed C# implement the events in the following a way:

```
class Shop
{
    internal event _EventHandler GoodsArrived;

    public void BringGoods(string goods)
    {
        if (GoodsArrived != null)
        {
            GoodsArrived(this, new GoodsInfoEventArgs(goods));
        }
    }
}
```

I mean without the delegate.

I am aware of how the event works in C#. It will just call all subscribed delegates in case there are any and it will be equal null otherwise. And also I am aware about the difference between the event and the delegate. The event allows only addition or subtraction of delegates, but does not allow to change the pointer (we can perform `+=` and `-=` operations on event, but we can not perform the `=` operation on event), while delegate allows all addition, subtraction and assign operations be performed. So, the event is a wrapper around the delegate and the wrapper allows to control in which way the delegate can change.

All that being said I do not understand the reasoning behind making it required to have a delegate defined in every place in program where we define an event.

In case you do not understand a part in my question, please, ask me about it and I will provide more info.

Thank you.

I am sorry for confusion. I meant, why not use something like this:

```
internal event _EventHandler(object sender, GoodsInfoEventArgs e) GoodsArrived;
```

?

Comment: How could you have an event, when not knowing its definition (delegate). If you subscribe something, you will always need to know the parameters and so on.. Or I dont understand your question, as your second code block does not work).

Comment: I actually don't fully understand what you mean with your second alternative example. In that code snippet, what would `_EventHandler` actually be? It's not declared anywhere, what should the compiler do with that?

Comment: And note that (in this example) you could simply use a `EventHandler<GoodsInfoEventArgs>` instead of declaring your own delegate (`GoodsInfoEventArgs` need to derive from `EventArgs` though).

Comment: How would you fire the event when you don´t know what arguments to provide? The delegate describes which arguments an event-handler-method will have and thus which arguments your fire-event-method should provide.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, why not specify the arguments directly in event declaration? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mention in your question, the event provides the mechanism so subscribe and unsubscribe. The delegate however is required to define the signature of the methods that can handle the event. There is a default signature (void with parameters sender and args), but you can use another type for EventArgs and also omit the sender parameter for instance.

In addition, there is a [pre-defined delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.7.2) `EventHandler` that you can use so you don't have to create the delegate yourself if you stick with the default signature and use `EventArgs` as arguments.

```
internal event EventHandler GoodsArrived;
```

If you want to provide a custom class for event arguments, you can use the [generic version of the delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
  // ...
}

internal event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> GoodsArrived;
```

---

As for your update, if you use one the out-of-the-box `EventHandler` delegates, you are almost there. You have a standard signature and do not need to create a delegate yourself.

The decision to base the events on delegates provides a lot of flexibility that you might or might not need. You can define events that use just the right set of parameters, also you can re-use existing delegates for multiple events. The default `EventHandler` implementations simplify things a lot and support you in defining an event that conforms to best practices (without taking away the flexibility).

From my point of view and experience, it would not add a lot to define the signature directly at the event. Just use an out-of-the-box `EventHandler` delegate; you can immediately recognize the signature and do not have to define the delegate yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question a little bit. I do not understand, why would the developers of the C# decide to tangle the `delegate` along with the `event`, why not specify all that the `event` needs to know directly in the `event` declaration? That would make things a lot clear. (It is somewhat similar problem to the constructor vs init function. Sometimes developers create the init function even though it would be possible to use only constructor. And eventually someone forgets to call the init function in the needed place and gets into trouble)